# Plot a parametric equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, parameterized

I have two sets of data: `[t1 ; x]` and `[t2 ; y]`, where the `t`s are in the same range for both, but possibly taking different values. A simple example:

```
[t1 ; x] = 
     1     2     4
     1     4    16

[t2 ; y] =
     1     3     5
     1     9    25
```

Here the underlying functions are simple: `x = t1.^2` and `y = t2.^2`. My goal is to get a plot of `x` versus `y`. Since the values taken by `t` aren't the same, I cannot simply use `plot(x,y)`. For the example, since `x == y`, I should get a line of slope `1`, but `plot(x,y)` isn't straight and neither piece has slope 1.

The application is much more complicated than this simple example, and I do not have an underlying function to generate data points. The data are sparse at times, so I cannot afford to lose information by throwing out points that are not in common between `t1` and `t2`.

I'm hoping that Matlab has some built in function that can take the two data sets and extract the dependence between `x` and `y` leaving `t` as an unseen parameter. Anyone know of such a function? In lieu of that, I'm open to suggestions for a good way to go about writing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using splines for this.

Given `tx`,`x`,`ty`,`y`, you can generate a graph of `x` vs `y` for a range of time points `timeRange` the following way using the [SPLINE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spline.html) command:

```
xx = spline(tx,x,timeRange); %# interpolate x vs time
yy = spline(ty,y,timeRange); %# interpolate y vs time

plot(xx,yy);
```

If the underlying data are noisy, then you may want to use smoothing splines (e.g. [CSAPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/csaps.html)), which need, however, the Curve Fitting Toolbox.

Comment: I like the sound of this. If I set timeRange to the union of tx and ty, that should incorporate all of my data, right? I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: @PengOne: It will incorporate all of your data as long as `timeRange` includes the minimum and maximum of `tx` and `ty`, respectively. To get a smoother curve, you can space points more densely in `timeRange`; such as `1:0.1:5` in your above example.