# plotting a parametric curve using an ordered data set in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, parametric-equations

This is an elementary question, which I hope has an easier solution that the one I have:  I have an Nx2 data A set which is a parametric curve in the 2D plane.  The set A is ordered, it is the solution of a differential equation.

How do I plot this?  There is `scatter`, but that may leave gaps (unless I make sure to add more points into the set, but I'd rather not do that).

There is also `ezplot`, but that is a bit annoying in that it only accepts functions as argument, so I have to create a function that interpolates each column of my data matrix `A`.

There must be a quick one-line way to "connect the dots" in a 2D data set??  The funny thing is, GNUplot does this automatically!...but unfortunately doesn't give the best looking plots, IMHO...

I found a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408320/plot-a-parametric-equation-in-matlab), but that is only for graphs of functions, which is not what I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your points are ordered correctly with respect to the parameter, then you can simply plot each point as the corresponding row in your matrix. If your matrix is `data` then you can simply do

```
 x = data(:,1)
 y = data(:,2)
 plot(x,y)
```

You can obviously combine those 3 lines into one for compactness.

Comment: Oh, ha, it's that easy, thank you! I thought `plot` was only for plotting graphs of functions and that it would interpret `x` as points input values of a function...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is using `plot` function. Suppose that your data is `A`:

```
plot( A(:,1),A(:,2));
```